WSL2 outbound connection failure to other local machine
In Windows 11 23 H2, I connect using PowerShell from WSL2 to remote servers and ping google.com responds.
I have another local Ubuntu machine available over the network. I can connect to it from  PowerShell, but when I ping it from  WSL2 (outbound connection):
$ ping myother-ubuntusystem
It returns the error:
ping: myother-ubuntusystem: Temporary failure in name resolution
From WSL2, ssh to myother-ubuntusystem also returns the same error.
I updated <homeprofile>/.wslconfig with the line networkingMode=mirrored, afterwards I've ran the cmd:
$ wsl --shutdown
and restarted wsl.
If I add the lines following lines in /etc/wsl.conf
[network]
generateResolvConf = false

then ping google.com and ping myother-ubuntusystem don't work but other remote machines are still accessible over ssh. My /etc/hosts looks like this:

# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       wslhostname.       wslhostname

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Note: I did my WSL2 ssh config setup using Nix home-manager

Probably mDNS is in use. Configure mDNS inside the WSL2 container.

What's the content of /etc/resolv.conf when you do NOT have generateResolvConf = false? Have you tried systemctl --now disable systemd-resolved (as root)?

On adding the line of generateResolvConf = false to wsl.conf, and rebooting wsl, the file: /etc/resolv.conf gets removed.
Also I figured out that the --networking-mode is still nat even after rebooting wsl. Perhaps, I should reboot the whole machine.
(Major networking changes are also expected in the upcoming wsl v2.3)

@Shah-G The case I asked is when you do NOT have the line / have the line REMOVED.

@Shah-G Btw, since your WSL distro is apparently NixOS, I suppose you need to try stopping and/or disabling systemd-resolved the Nix way.
